# subprocess.CalledProcessError not giving error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am using below code for getting output of shell command.

```
import subprocess
exitcode, err, out = 0, None, None
try:
    out = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    exitcode, err = e.returncode, e.output

print("x{} e{} o{}".format(exitcode, err, out))
```

When a valid command is being passed for `cmd` like `echo hello`, the program is running fine and giving output as `(0, None, "hello\n")`

But if I give a wrong kind of command I am expecting the error message should come in `err`, but its getting printed directly. For example if I pass `ls -lrt foo` in `cmd` the output is coming as

```
anirban@desktop> python mytest.py
ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory
x2 e oNone
```

So I want `ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory` should be coming in `err`. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To capture the error output, you need to pass in another argument to the `subprocess.check_output()` function. You need to set `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`. This will channel the stderr output to `e.output`.

`subprocess.check_output()` is a wrapper over `subprocess.run()`. It makes our lives easier by passing in some sensible defaults. One of those is making `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`. This directs the standard output of the command you are running back to your program. Similarly, you can direct the standard error output to your program by passing in argument, `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`, this will populate `e.stderr` where `e` is the exception.

Let me know if this is not clear.